# ClassNotFoundException when using ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I got this common exception when using ProGuard. However, I couldn't really figure out a way to fix this.

When code is ran through ProGuard, I get this exception when running:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbyb>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/customtabs/CustomTabsServiceConnection;
    at boolean com.google.android.gms.internal.zzgr.a(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
    at void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni$zza.d(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
    at void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni$zza.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni) ((null):-1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni com.google.android.gms.internal.zznj$1.a() ((null):-1)
    at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.zznj$1.call() ((null):-1)
    at void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpn$3.run() ((null):-1)
    at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:428)
    at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:237)
    at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/me.manabreak.bandit.free-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/me.manabreak.bandit.free-1/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    at boolean com.google.android.gms.internal.zzgr.a(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
    at void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni$zza.d(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
    at void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni$zza.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni) ((null):-1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni com.google.android.gms.internal.zznj$1.a() ((null):-1)
    at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.zznj$1.call() ((null):-1)
    at void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpn$3.run() ((null):-1)
    at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:428)
    at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:237)
    at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:761)
```

I tried adding these rows to my ProGuard file:

```
-keep class android.support.customtabs.CustomServiceConnection {*; }
-keep class android.support.customtabs.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.support.customtabs.** {*; }
```

But it didn't help. How do I fix this?

Comment: found any solution? I'm having the same problem u.u

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have included Google Design Support Library in your project. You can include it in your app level Gradle file like this -

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
```